# What WCF client files do I need to check into SVN

Tags: wcf, svn, wcf-client

I have added a service reference to my visual studio project, and now I want to check that project into SVN. My question is, which of the files need to be checked in for the next person to be able to build the project. The files created include .svcinfo .xsd .disco .datasource .wsdl .cs and .svcmap.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need all of them.

Well, you may not actually heed the .datasource files, but Microsoft thought you'd like them, so you'd just as well keep them.

Comment: why can't they be regenerated with just the url of the service?

Comment: You will have issues with CI if you don't include the files, technically you can just regen everything, but you will have to add it as a step in your build process.